# Select a folder with a single click using askdirectory in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to select a "folder" in `tkinter` using only a single click? 
Right now I am using `filedialog.askdirectory`, but doing so I have to double click on the required folder to get it's name back in my GUI.

I tried `askopenfilename` but it only gives the file name not the folder name. Is there any work around for it?

I checked few websites but mainly followed the link [tkFileDialog](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) and [select multiple folders](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2011-January/002735.html).

Thanks!

Comment: In order to understand your problem, why do you need this to work with a single click?

Comment: The gui I am working on is for a 7" touch screen display which is not a very good digitizer. But I have to use the touch for my project. Sometime it's very annoying to select elements with the touch. To get around this problem, I made the buttons, scrollbars, etc larger. However, I am unable to change the size of the elements of the pop-up window created by "askdirectory". So, if I can select it with a single click then I could minimize the annoyance.

Comment: You can write some dialog yourself ;) Are u trying to do "touch display" app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know tkinter innards, but a single Button-1 click seems to select the item no matter what.  So, use the ButtonRelease-1, for example

```
<Listbox>.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.handleList)
```

where  stands for an object that supports bind.

Being a person new to Python, please correct or remove if appropriate.

Comment: I didn't know that using angle brackets removes its contents, so a reference to an object, call it Object precedes .bind and follows where.